# PlayOnLinux “Error in main glxinfo is not installed. Please install mesa-utils package” LeagueOfLegends

Tags: 14.04

I am currently trying to install League of Legends using PlayOnLinux, but every time I do I get this error:

```
Error in main glxinfo is not installed. Please install mesa-utils package
```

What should I do to fix this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do exactly as it says: install `mesa-utils`.

You can do so by opening a terminal, and typing

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Entering your password and "y" when prompted. You can also install it through the software center.